# How do I stop Windows from messing with the layout of my applications when I turn my monitor on?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

[So here's a video of what happens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R1v2pTuAILw): I have one monitor connected via displayport, and another via hdmi. If I turn off the DP monitor (as seen in the video), or let it go to standby mode, when it turns back on again, the OS (Windows) will move every application window to the DP screen (which is also set as the primary monitor, if that makes any difference).

This is infuriating, some applications (i.e. games) don't respond well to this and might change resolution or crash entirely, and I have to move each one back one by one. I also can't simply use `WindowsKey + Shift + Arrow` to move the window as the two monitors are different resolutions, and the windows don't reappear where they were before, so I still have to drag them using the mouse anyway.

I just want it to stop, and turning off monitor standby or leaving the monitor on all the time is not a solution (I'd rather not waste electricity and risk monitor burn-in).

Thank you :)

Comment: I would assume that your windows are not bound to your monitor(s) but to the primary/secondary monitor. If you power down the DP/primary monitor the HDMI monitor gets primary monitor and all windows on it are getting connected to the primary monitor. If you then switch on the DP monitor the primary monitor changes and therefore all windows bound to the primary monitor also switch to the DP monitor.

Comment: Standby shouldn't do this, it should still be registered as present. You'd need to check with the manufacturer why their product doesn't support correct protocols. Powering it off definitely will, & also reassign your Primary, as you've already noticed. There is no way round this except to not switch it off.

Comment: @Tetsujin Changing the primary monitor isn't really an option, as a lot of [older] games tend to just render to the primary monitor and have no awareness of multi monitor setups :(

Comment: @Robert This being the case, what can I do? Do you know of some configuration I can change regarding this?

Comment: The easiest way would be not to make a monitor primary that is switched off frequently.